# What is page_fast_cache?

Tags: caching

The [Cache Router](http://drupal.org/project/cacherouter) module advertises that it "has an option to utilize the page_fast_cache part of Drupal in order to reduce the amount of resources needed for serving pages to anonymous users."

However, the only Google hits for "drupal page_fast_cache" point back to cacherouter.

What *is* page_fast_cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the project page is referring to [page_cache_fastpath()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/page_cache_fastpath/6), which is called during Drupal bootstrap from the following code:

```
if (variable_get('page_cache_fastpath', FALSE) && page_cache_fastpath()) {
  exit;
}
```

The documentation page reports the following description for the function:

> By implementing `page_cache_fastpath()`, a special cache handler can skip most of the bootstrap process, including the database connection. This function is invoked during DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_EARLY_PAGE_CACHE.

The example code reported in that page helps to understand how the function needs to be implemented, and what should do.

```
function page_cache_fastpath() {
  $page = mycache_fetch($base_root . request_uri(), 'cache_page');
  if (!empty($page)) {
    drupal_page_header();
    print $page;
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

If the module reports to utilize it, it means it actually defines the `page_cache_fastpath()` function, which is called by Drupal core code.
To notice that it's not a hook, but a function. This means that a module called "mycache" doesn't need to implement `mycache_page_cache_fastpath()`, but `page_cache_fastpath()`. In fact, the bootstrap code is explicitly calling `page_cache_fastpath()`, as it is evident in the code I reported at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Looks like a very promising lead, thanks. Keeping the Q open until I work out if that's really what they mean :)

Comment: Yes, Kiam's answer is correct.  It skips the database connection - obviously this only works if your cache_page bin is backed by some non-database storage (such as Memcached or APC).